# Proving beta function property: $ B(a,b) B(a+b,c) = B(b,c) B(a,b+c) $

Tags: calculus, beta-function

How to prove beta function property:
$$
\mathrm{B}(a,b) \mathrm{B}(a+b,c) = \mathrm{B}(b,c) \mathrm{B}(a,b+c)
$$

using Beta function definition.

$$
\mathrm{B}(a,b) = \int_0^1x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}dx.
$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Hint:  Consider the usual expression for $B(x,y)$ in terms of the gamma function.

Comment: actually no much  $$ \mathrm{B}(a,b) B(a+b,c) = \int_0^1(x^{b-1}(1-x)^{b+c-1}x^{a-1}(1-x)^{c-1})dx.$$

Comment: I have tried the gamma function but it does not work for me either

Comment: It is not true that $\int_0^1 f(x)dx\times \int_0^1 g(x)dx=\int_0^1 f(x)\times g(x)dx$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relationship between the $\Gamma$ function and the $B$ function is given by the following identity:
$$
B(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}.
$$

Using this equality, your original equation can be re-written as
$$
\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}\cdot \frac {\Gamma(a+b)\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(a+b+c)}=
\frac{\Gamma(b)\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(b+c)}\cdot\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b+c)}{\Gamma(a+b+c)}
$$
which can immediately be seen to hold.